# Is there any special convention or standard on how should I validate an input?

Tags: android, validation

I mean the front-end part of the validation. Should there be a submit button which checks all the fields or a text-change-listener which gives **live** feedback if the input is correct and so on?

Comment: You can use two-way data binding to validate user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer: that depends.

Put yourself in the shoes of a *user* of your application. What gives you a better experience:

1. You enter data in 10 different fields, and in the end, you are told: there are 5 errors, now go and fix this, and that, and that
2. You enter data into a field, and you get immediate feedback when something is wrong

Meaning: both attempts work, and both are used by different apps. Most people might find the second option more convenient though.

Long story short: there is no common best practice. Each app is different. If you really want to compete in the market, check out what your *competition* is doing, and then design a **better** user experience than that competition!